# How to generate arxml file from nested C++ file

Tags: embedded, autosar, automotive

I am new to autosar adaptive platform for embedded application. I have a C++ header file with a nested datastructure as mentioned below.  Appreciate if someone can suggest a way/document with the rules to convert this nested data structure to arxml file.

```
typedef struct xyz {
   int a;
   char* string;
} A;
 
typedef struct abc {
   A a;
} B;

typedef struct efg {
   B b;
} C;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create a model of your data structure if the data structure is supposed to be passed to one of the ara-APIs. If that‘s the case, then you can read the relevant information about the modeling of data types on the adaptive platform in the AUTOSAR specification TPS Manifest Specification.

Please note that there‘s an additional aspect to take into account. If your data structure has been created to represent physical quantities, then it might be advised to not only create an implementation-level model of your data structure, but also consider creating a model on the physical level, i.e. using an `ApplicationDataType`.

The modeling of `ApplicationDataType`s is described in the document TPS Software Component Template.